# Prevent spring errors on webpage

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, error-handling

I am using spring MVC 3. 
I validate various users input and show errors as applicable.

But this often to show the spring errors like `org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException` etc being shown on UI. How can i prevent the output of these errors on webpage ?

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to achieve. If you want to resolve the exception please put the full stackstrace and the validation section of code.

Comment: I want the DispatcherServlet to catch all spring errors instead of output on browser

Comment: If you want to resolve exception, you can follow this tutorial.http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exceptionhandler-example/

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:**
>
> I understand that for topic starter my answer may be no longer
>   relevant. But it can be useful for those who have visited this page to
>   search for solutions to similar problems.

### Answer:

In order to prevent the output of errors on web page, you may handle them. There are several types of error handling, that you may use for this in Spring MVC 3.x and above:

1. Controller-based exception handling
2. Global exception handling
3. [Other methods, that are bit more complicated](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#going-deeper)

#### Controller-based exception handling

You can add an @ExceptionHandler annotation on methods inside a controller. Such methods will function as error handlers for exceptions thrown from methods annotated as @RequestMapping in the same controller.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("exception", e);
    modelAndView.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    modelAndView.setViewName("error");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

#### Global exception handling

A controller advice allows you to apply exception handling across the whole application, not just to an individual controller. In other words, handling will apply to exceptions thrown from any controller.

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    public static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW = "error";

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public void handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("exception", e);
        modelAndView.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
        modelAndView.setViewName(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

> **For more info:**
>
> - [Exception Handling in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)